# scrreprt - add levels below \subparagraph

Tags: sectioning, koma-script, sections-paragraphs

I have to write my thesis in (German) law and we usually use a very nested headline system.
I use `scrreprt` and have these levels:

- (part)
- chapter
- section
- subsection
- subsubsection
- paragraph
- subparagraph

But I need at least 3 more levels. They don't have to be in the ToC but it would be nice.

I searched a lot and found a snippet that works but I can't reproduce it and create more levels.

```
% Fügt Gliederungsebene \subsubparagraph hinzu.
\titleclass{\subsubparagraph}{straight}[\subparagraph]
\makeatletter
\newcounter{subsubsubsection}[subsubsection] \newcounter{subsubparagraph}[subparagraph]
\newcommand*\l@subsubparagraph{\bprot@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{6em}}
\makeatother
```

---

Somewhat related is my second question. Is there any way to rename some of the levels? It's always a little annoying trying to remember what comes after subsubsection etc.
Maybe `\chapter`, `\section`, `\sub1section`, `\sub2section`, `\sub3section` or something else.

Your help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: What should the formatting of these newly created sublevels be? **Bold**, *italic*, indented or not? Also, using numbers in control sequences would complicate its usage. It's easier to use `\subAsection`, `\subBsection`, or something similar with letters and not numbers.

Comment: well sure subAsection would work too. I currently use: \titlespacing{\subsubparagraph}{0em}{0em}{0em}  
\titleformat{\subsubparagraph}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubparagraph\quad}{0pt}{}

Comment: We'd like to keep answers separate from questions, so you should write a separate answer instead of editing your answer into the question. Self-answers are perfectly admissible, and a well-written answer may earn you additional reputation.

Comment: The Jura package is specifically created for German legal documents. The documentation is only in German but perhaps you could see if it provides an answer.

Comment: well the `Jura` class is 14 years old. The `juramisc` package is kind of nice and I've tried it. They implemented the levels relative, so you don't use `\section` but you start and use `\toc{test}` for the same and `\sub{test1}` for a level below that. But you have to remember to use `\levelup`. It doesn't keep up with my writing style though since I move some parts around sometimes so it's easier for me to use fixed levels and I try to keep the code in my text to a minimum. My 3 extra levels are more than enough and using them is the exception really.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quoting the [manual](http://texdoc.org/pkg/titlesec) from the [`titlesec` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/titlesec):

> With the help of classes you may insert, say, a new subchapter level between chapter and section, or creating a scheme of your own.

(at subsection 3.9 in the `titlesec.pdf`).

At appendix 9.2, it shows exactly how the already existing sections and the like are defined; don't copy the already existing parts to your file, but use them as inspiration for defining new ones (amount of indentation, style, etc). My advice is to look at all the appendices and subsection 3.9.

Comment: Thanks fort he revision Joseph, it looks really nice. I'll pay attention to it. (remove when you read this)

Answer (score 2):

Since the question is about a KOMA-class, we can use KOMA features to define new levels of structuring commands.

[image: niclasKomaExtraLevel]

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\makeatletter
\DeclareSectionCommand[%
  tocindent=9.0em,%
  ]{subparagraph}
\DeclareSectionCommand[%
  style=section,%
  level=6,%
  indent=2.0\scr@parindent,%
  beforeskip=3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex,%
  afterskip=-1em,%
  tocstyle=subsection,%
  tocindent=10.0em,%
  tocnumwidth=4.1em%
  ,font=\normalcolor\normalsize\bfseries\sffamily,%
]{Aparagraph}
\DeclareSectionCommand[%
  style=section,%
  level=7,%
  indent=3.0\scr@parindent,%
  beforeskip=3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex,%
  afterskip=-1em,%
  tocstyle=subsection,%
  tocindent=11.0em,%
  tocnumwidth=4.1em%
  ,font=\normalcolor\normalsize\bfseries\sffamily,%
]{Bparagraph}
\DeclareSectionCommand[%
  style=section,%
  level=8,%
  indent=4.0\scr@parindent,%
  beforeskip=3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus.2ex,%
  afterskip=-1em,%
  tocstyle=subsection,%
  tocindent=12.0em,%
  tocnumwidth=4.1em%
  ,font=\normalcolor\normalsize\bfseries\sffamily,%
]{Cparagraph}
\makeatother
\setcounter{tocdepth}{7}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Wombat}
\subsection{Capybara}
\subsubsection{Mara}
\paragraph{Zebra}
\subparagraph{Elephant}
\Aparagraph{Giraffe}
\Bparagraph{Quail}
\Cparagraph{Duck}
\end{document}
```

Of course you don't really need `\makeatletter` and `\makeitother` if you don't use low level commands. I used them, because i copied the bits straight from the class file.

Comment: I was wondering how would one add numbering to the lower levels like 1.1.1.1 Zebra, etc.?

Comment: @Louis `\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}` The number corresponds to the level.

Comment: You might need to define the counters for the lower levels, but there is a point when numbering gets a bit pointless `\renewcommand{\theAparagraph}{\thesubparagraph.\arabic{Aparagraph}}`

Comment: TNX. I think I missed setting secnumdepth. I know it becomes pointless, but some places want it that way and then that is wat one should give them.

Answer (score 0):

So thanks to everyone. I kind of fixed it:

```
\titleclass{\subAparagraph}{straight}[\subparagraph]
\makeatletter
\newcounter{subAparagraph}[subparagraph]
\newcommand*\l@subAparagraph{\bprot@dottedtocline{6}{12em}{2.5em}}
\makeatother

\titleclass{\subBparagraph}{straight}[\subAparagraph]
\makeatletter
\newcounter{subBparagraph}[subAparagraph]
\newcommand*\l@subBparagraph{\bprot@dottedtocline{7}{14em}{2.5em}}
\makeatother

\titleclass{\subCparagraph}{straight}[\subBparagraph]
\makeatletter
\newcounter{subCparagraph}[subBparagraph]
\newcommand*\l@subCparagraph{\bprot@dottedtocline{8}{16em}{2.5em}}
\makeatother
```

I use alnumsec to make the Symbols:

```
\usepackage{alnumsec}
\alnumsectionlevels{0}{chapter,section,subsection,subsubsection,paragraph,subparagraph,subAparagraph,subBparagraph,subCparagraph}
\otherseparators{4}
\surroundarabic[(][)]{}{.}
\surroundgreek[][)]{}{.}
\alnumsecstyle{LRaldagbr}
```

And formating:

```
\titlespacing{\subAparagraph}{0em}{0em}{0em}
\titlespacing{\subBparagraph}{0em}{0em}{0em}
\titlespacing{\subCparagraph}{0em}{0em}{0em}
\titleformat{\subAparagraph}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubAparagraph\quad}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subBparagraph}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubBparagraph\quad}{0pt}{}
\titleformat{\subCparagraph}[hang]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubCparagraph\quad}{0pt}{}
```

---

I also noticed (after writing one paper with near identical settings and not noticing this) that the counter was not resetting if the exact previous level was not called.

[image: Reset Counter]

I fixed this with adding every "higher" level to reset (`\usepackage{remreset}`)

```
\makeatletter

\@addtoreset{subCparagraph}{part}
\@addtoreset{subCparagraph}{chapter}
\@addtoreset{subCparagraph}{section}
\@addtoreset{subCparagraph}{subsection}
\@addtoreset{subCparagraph}{subsubsection}
\@addtoreset{subCparagraph}{paragraph}
\@addtoreset{subCparagraph}{subparagraph}
\@addtoreset{subCparagraph}{subAparagraph}
\makeatother
```

(This also affects the default levels like section)

This is kind of a bulky macro since you have to add something similar (only add the higher levels) for every level and I guess I will remove it so that I can see where I made an enumeration error :)