# Creating a subsubparagraph

Tags: sectioning, sections-paragraphs

I want to create a `subsubparagraph` heading (in order to comply with phd guidlines for formatting). I've copied code from `article.cls` and just made everything 'lower'. However, when I do, although the `subsubparagraph` exists, it prints the title twice.

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\makeatletter
\newcounter{subsubparagraph}[subparagraph]
\renewcommand\thesubsubparagraph{\thesubparagraph.\@arabic\c@subsubparagraph}
\newcommand\subsubparagraph{\@startsection{subsubparagraph}{6}{\parindent}%
                                       {3.25ex \@plus1ex \@minus .2ex}%
                                       {-1em}%
                              {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand*\l@subsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{10em}{5em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Foo}
\subparagraph{Bar}
\subsubparagraph{Foo bar!!!}

\end{document}
```

[image: seeing double when defining subsubparagraph]

The `subsubparagraph` needs to have all the properties of `subparagraph`, with possible additional indentation (which currently I've omitted to keep the new code as close to that found in `article.cls`)

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66349/scrreprt-add-levels-below-subparagraph, although the answer was not spelt out, only pointed to. Also, this behaviour is still bizarre.

Comment: Add `\newcommand{\subsubparagraphmark}[1]{}`. I don't see why an additional sectional unit is needed, as already five below `\chapter` are provided.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

There is no need to load new packages.

In order to define a new sectional unit "foo" you need:

1. the command `\foo`, usually defined in terms of `\@startsection`
2. a counter, usually with the same name, `foo`
3. a command for setting the entry in the table of contents, `\l@foo`
4. a command for possibly setting the mark, `\foomark`

So the complete definition would be

```
\makeatletter
\newcounter{subsubparagraph}[subparagraph]
\renewcommand\thesubsubparagraph{%
  \thesubparagraph.\@arabic\c@subsubparagraph}
\newcommand\subsubparagraph{%
  \@startsection{subsubparagraph}    % counter
    {6}                              % level
    {\parindent}                     % indent
    {3.25ex \@plus 1ex \@minus .2ex} % beforeskip
    {-1em}                           % afterskip
    {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}}
\newcommand\l@subsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{10em}{5em}}
\newcommand{\subsubparagraphmark}[1]{}
\makeatother
```

Answer (score 6):

Using the `titlesec` package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleclass{\subsubparagraph}{straight}[\subparagraph]
\newcounter{subsubparagraph}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubparagraph}{\Alph{subsubparagraph}}
\titleformat{\subsubparagraph}[runin]{\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubparagraph} {\parindent}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}

\begin{document}
\paragraph{Foo}
\subparagraph{Bar}
\subsubparagraph{Foo bar!!!}

\end{document}
```

If for some reason you add `\setcounter{tocdepth}{6}` to get `subsubparagraph` to appear in the table of contents and include the `hyperref` package, you will need to include

```
\makeatletter
\def\toclevel@subsubparagraph{6}
\makeatother
```

In order for the pdf index to be made properly.