# How to stop new subsubparagraph entry appearing in TOC

Tags: sectioning, titlesec

I added a new subsubparagraph section level using the titlesec package, with help from [How to add an extra level of sections with headings below \subsubsection](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/60209/how-to-add-an-extra-level-of-sections-with-headings-below-subsubsection/60212#60212) and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/94404/98753.

The in-text titles are fine but the new label is added to the TOC with a page number. I can remove it by adding an asterisk to the call: `\subsubparagraph*{New label}`. But is there a way to build this into the titleformat instead?

A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]
  {\bfseries\small}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0em}

\titleformat{\subparagraph}[hang]
  {\bfseries\small}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{32pt}{0.5em}{0em}

\titleclass{\subsubparagraph}{straight}[\subparagraph]
\newcounter{subsubparagraph}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubparagraph}{\arabic{subsubparagraph}}
\titleformat{\subsubparagraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubparagraph}{32pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph} 
  \subparagraph{Subparagraph 1} 
  \subparagraph{Subparagraph 2}
    \subsubparagraph{New label}
      Finally, some ordinary text. I don't want a whole Lorem ipsum paragraph, so I'll just manually add a couple of lines.
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
\end{document}
```

[image: Screen capture of document produced]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to define `\l@subsubparagraph`, e.g.

```
\makeatletter
\newcommand\l@subsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{7em}}
\makeatother
```

The first argument of `\@dottedtocline` defines the toclevel of `\subsubparagraph`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[raggedright]{titlesec}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}

\titleformat{\paragraph}[hang]
  {\bfseries\small}{\theparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\paragraph}{0pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{0em}

\titleformat{\subparagraph}[hang]
  {\bfseries\small}{\thesubparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing{\subparagraph}{32pt}{0.5em}{0em}

\titleclass{\subsubparagraph}{straight}[\subparagraph]
\newcounter{subsubparagraph}
\renewcommand{\thesubsubparagraph}{\arabic{subsubparagraph}}
\titleformat{\subsubparagraph}[runin]
  {\normalfont\normalsize\bfseries}{\thesubsubparagraph}{1em}{}
\titlespacing*{\subsubparagraph}{32pt}{3.25ex plus 1ex minus .2ex}{1em}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\l@subsubparagraph{\@dottedtocline{6}{14em}{7em}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Section}
\subsection{Subsection}
\subsubsection{Subsubsection}
\paragraph{Paragraph} 
  \subparagraph{Subparagraph 1} 
  \subparagraph{Subparagraph 2}
    \subsubparagraph{New label}
      Finally, some ordinary text. I don't want a whole Lorem ipsum paragraph, so I'll just manually add a couple of lines.
\subsubsection{Subsubsection 2}
\end{document}
```