# Numbering subsubsections with letters

Tags: sectioning

I'm currently writing a thesis and I need to divide the sections of my chapters beyond the conventional numeric subsubsection. It's the reason why I use an asterisk *. But I'd like to change that way of ordering my sections and change the numeric section beyond subsubsection to an alphabetical order. How could I do that?

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsubsection*}}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\section{Title}

\subsection{Title}

\subsubsection{Title}

\subsubsection*{Title}

\chapter{Second}

\end{document}
```

Comment: [scrreprt - add levels below \subparagraph](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/327795)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the standard `LaTeX` classes the sectional divisions are `\part`, `\chapter` (but not in `article`), `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`, `\paragraph`, and `\subparagraph`. Perhaps you could try using `\paragraph` and `\subparagraph` as a first go to get your lower level headings and then, if needs be, ask about changing the numbering from numeric to alphabetic.

Comment: I think I'm searching for a subsubsubsection that doesn't exist and I don't want to use \paragraph for obscur aesthetic reasons. Maybe I'd be happy if only I could find a type of section similar to enumerate environment with no margins.

Comment: @domi: Then look at the definition of `\subsubsection` using it as a basis for your `\subsubsubsection` and make your custom changes.

Answer (score 8):

Three changes: 1) you need to renew `\thesubsubsection`, not `\thesubsection`; Get rid of the `*` at the end of that redefinition; and 3) set `secnumdepth` to 4.

Your question is still vague enough that I am not sure if this addresses  your needs.

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesection.\alph{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}


\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\section{sTitle}

\subsection{ssTitle}

\subsubsection{sssTitle}

\subsubsection{sssTitle}

\chapter{Second}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Though perhaps this is what you mean, since the above approach will reset the subsubsection counter whenever a new subsection is invoked:

```
\documentclass{book}

\renewcommand{\thesubsubsection}{\thesubsection.\alph{subsubsection}}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{4}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}

\section{sTitle}

\subsection{ssTitle}

\subsubsection{sssTitle}

\subsubsection{sssTitle}

\chapter{Second}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I need a toc depth superior to 3 : 1.1.1.1 Can we built a subsection that would be superior to 4 without using paragraph?

Comment: @domi LaTeX has it built in to call it "paragraph".  See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/529794/overriding-commands/529802#529802

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble with this, but I fixed it by putting a space before my `.`

```
\renewcommand{\thesubsection}{\thesection .\alph{subsubsection*}}
```